# Why is next() function 'in place' for csv.reader objects but not for list iterators?

Tags: python, csv

According to python documentation for `next()` function:

> `next(iterator[, default])`:
> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its `__next__()` method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise `StopIteration` is raised.

My question: Why is it 'in place' when used like below:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

This skips the first line of the file. I thought it should be like this instead:

```
csv_reader = next(csv_reader)
```

Comment: The line `next(csv_reader)` is just so that your code skips the CSV header line.

Comment: What happens when you substitute the line of code you think should be there?

Comment: The csv_reader will be the header with list type.
So you said the next skips the header only? I tried it with two times next() and it skips the non-header lines also.@quamrana

Comment: Why did you use two times `next()`? I meant it as a demonstration. You think the line should be: `csv_reader = next(csv_reader)`. You should try replacing the proper line with the line you think should be there and report what the resulting output is.

Comment: My problem raises here actually. It returns the next item. But why the iterator goes to the next item also. I mean why it is in place. It is not like this for lists for example.@FilipMüller

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: But where have you ever seen: `csv_reader = next(csv_reader)`? This has very limited utility.

Comment: `csv_reader` is a iterator and it is special object which keeps information which element return next time.

Comment: Maybe my question is not descriptive enough? I want to know why we can't do this for list for example. like this: 
``` 
i = iter(list)
next(i) 
```
this does not move the iterator to next item.
but here it does.
why is that?@quamrana

Comment: `list` is not iterator - it doesn't keep information which element returns next time.

Comment: This isn't related to the `with` block.  If you just opened the file with no `with` clause, you'd see just the same behaviour.

Comment: Please update your question with all these examples. This will show us what you are thinking so we can spot where your are making your mistake.

Comment: you can do `i = iter([1,2,3])` `next(i)` and you will get next elements

Comment: When I use iter(list_name) it creates a iterator to list. and when using next() like in a 'with block' it does not move the iterator@furas

Comment: it has nothing to do with `with ...` - but when I use `print(next(i))` and again `print(next(i))` then I get next elements,.

Comment: I am asking about it being in place or not .
I know next() will give me the next item.@furas

Comment: @Azimi what do you mean by *in place*?

Comment: @Azimi2kht *"i = iter(list); next(i) does not move the iterator to next item"*.  Yes it does - see this example to demonstrate it: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY0xDoMwEAR7v2KlNBi5CaTNG/IARAHkCCeZM7KPBF7vWJHS7sxot1OXIG3OHnd0V4fGoXW49YbLwEqx8tYIHVqxNVtk0ao76rrBHCIOsIB7C1zwEH@iBXlaSTQ5jDQNeyJ8CFukN4c9FWMKkvaVntCFMHNM@k8wFjp4z/LC79Dm/AU "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @FilipMüller: I think the OP is using the term `in place` like: `lst.sort()` sorts a list in place.

Comment: But your code in [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY0xDoMwEAR7v2KlNBi5CaTNG/IARAHkCCeZM7KPBF7vWJHS7sxot1OXIG3OHnd0V4fGoXW49YbLwEqx8tYIHVqxNVtk0ao76rrBHCIOsIB7C1zwEH@iBXlaSTQ5jDQNeyJ8CFukN4c9FWMKkvaVntCFMHNM@k8wFjp4z/LC79Dm/AU) shows that it moves iterator to next item. Output doesn't display `1*2` because `next(i)` was moving iterator to `2` which gives `2*2` as first element on list

Comment: the doc does not mention it being in place or not. Why is that?
it says it calls __next__() method. and doc for __next__() does not mention anything about being 'in place' just like next().@quamrana

Comment: @Azimi2kht the doc does say that it "retrieves" the next element of the iterator.  It might have been clearer to use the word "returns".  But how could the function be said to "retrieve" the next value if it didn't return it (like if it returned the iterator object instead?)

Comment: @Azimi2kht: I don't know where you get the idea of `in place` from. Yes, `next(reader)` calls `reader.__next__()`.

Comment: Definition - In-place operation is an operation that changes directly the content of a given linear algebra, vector, matrices(Tensor) without making a copy. 
@quamrana
just a simple search gave me this.

Comment: Ok, well if you want to use that terminology, then fine. Yes, `reader` is modified in place when using `next(reader)`. The `reader` is an object in its own right and has state which can be modified in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next` returns the next item of the iterator, not the "rest" of the iterator after it removes this next item. So if you save the result of `next(csv_reader)` into `csv_reader`, you will have the first line of the file saved  in `csv_reader` and will have lost the iterator.

An example:

```py
my_iterator = iter([1, 2, 3])
result = next(my_iterator)
print(result)  # prints 1
second_result = next(my_iterator)
print(second_result)  # prints 2
```

Notice how we always call `next()` on the same iterator object. We don't need to reassign it, it just keeps giving us the elements one by one, keeping track which one it should return next.

`next` can be used to skip some of the elements like so:

```py
my_iterator = iter([1, 2, 3])
next(my_iterator)  # returns 1, but we don't want to store it, we just want to move past it
for element in my_iterator:
    print(element)
# will print 2 and 3
```

#### Iterators versus lists

Sometimes there is confusion about iterators and lists. A list itself is not an iterator, but an *iterable*. That means we can use `for x in lst` to automatically create an iterator over the list. So

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
for e in my_list:
    pass
```

actually behind the scenes works somewhat like this:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3]

# create an iterator from the list for the loop
my_list_iterator = iter(my_list)
for e in my_list_itetator:
    pass
# and get rid of the iterator after the loop
del my_list_iterator
```